# rounding floats in python (handling 5s)

Tags: python, rounding

I am trying figure out the best way to robustly round floats in python using the round half up algorithm. It seems the best way to do this is using the decimal library. However I would expect this method to carry over the rounding up of a 5 across a float. For example:

```
from decimal import *
Decimal('3.445').quantize(Decimal('0.1'), rounding=ROUND_HALF_UP)
```

The result is 3.4. What I would expect the algorithm to do is carry over the round up of the 5 such that 3.445 = 3.45 = 3.5.

Does anybody know how to do this in python? I cannot seem to find a robust way of doing this.

Comment: I never heard of that way of rounding before. If I understood correctly, `3.44444444445` also should be rounded to `3.5`, right?

Comment: Yes. I need to round this way given the problem I am trying to solve

Comment: What a strange behavior. It's like repeatedly propagating rounding error. Are you sure this is what you want? Could you give us more information about what you need this for?

Answer (score 1):

Rounding half up doesn't work by carrying over the round-ups from lower digits, but simply determines the half point at the given exponent. Since 3.445 % 0.1 == 0.045, which is less than half of 0.1, it would correctly round down to 3.4.

You can instead implement the desired rounding logic by rounding half up the given decimal number from the second-least significant digit to the given target exponent in a loop:

```
def round_half_up_carryover(d, target_exp):
    exp = Decimal(10) ** (d.as_tuple()[2] + 1)
    while exp <= target_exp:
        d = d.quantize(exp.normalize(), rounding=ROUND_HALF_UP)
        exp *= 10
    return d
```

so that:

```
print(round_half_up_carryover(Decimal('3.445'), Decimal('0.1')))
```

would output:

```
3.5
```

Comment: Ok makes sense. So is there a python method that does what I am intending?

Comment: No there is not. What you are describing is definitely not any of the established methods for rounding, so you would have to implement the logics on your own.

Comment: I've updated the answer with a sample implementation of the said logics.